# Apache 2.4.25 Make failed due to PCRE cannot find pcre.h

Tags: apache-httpd, solaris, make, error-handling, pcre

I use Solaris 11. pcre.h exist in /opt/app/pcre/lib but Make cannot detect it.How can I include /opt/app/pcre/lib during make?

```
Apache 2.4.25 configure:
CC='/opt/app/solarisstudio12.4/bin/cc' CPP='/opt/app/solarisstudio12.4/bin/cc -E' ./configure --prefix=/opt/app/apache --with-pcre=/opt/app/pcre/bin/pcre2-config

Here is the log:
"util_pcre.c", line 49: cannot find include file: "pcre.h"
"util_pcre.c", line 104: undefined symbol: pcre_free
"util_pcre.c", line 104: function designator is not of function type
"util_pcre.c", line 105: cannot recover from previous errors
cc: acomp failed for util_pcre.c
gmake[2]: *** [util_pcre.lo] Error 1
gmake[2]: Leaving directory `/export/home/admin/Downloads/httpd-2.4.2/server'
gmake[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/export/home/admin/Downloads/httpd-2.4.2/server'
gmake: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Apache 2.4 is expecting `pcre`, and you're building with `pcre2`, which is [not compatible](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57471).

FWIW, the Solaris `pcre` package should work nicely for you, unless you're specifically building everything from scratch.

Comment: This, you can also look into OpenCSW for the packages so you don't have to compile yourself.

Comment: Pcre2 is incompatible. /usr/bin/pcre-config Failed. I also downloaded,installed, and used pcre-8.70. Also failed. There are something I missed.

Comment: So, i found what i am missing. GCC got confused when the pcre lib is 32bit while what i try to compile is 64 bit. So, I remake everything with proper environment and retest all lib is in 64 bit. Voila . Problem solved.

Comment: Great catch.  It's often something that seems so simple in retrospect that stymies us for days. :)